# How to display Office365 calendar items in default Gnome Calendar

Tags: office365, gnome-calendar

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My primary email and calendar servers are Office365 at school. I *cannot* add it as an account (Settings > Online Accounts, etc.). I'm using BlueMail and it does sync both my email and calendar. I'd like the my calendar's events to show up in the default Gnome calendar. Is that possible?

Comment: The way to add it is via online accounts. Why can't you add your Microsoft account?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Don't know the exact reason, but if I try connecting as Microsoft Exchange, I get an error, code 4, "unexpected response from server." It's a university-based Office365 account.

Comment: Yours should be a standard Microsoft account for all intended purposes, not Microsoft Exchange.

Comment: No, the standard Microsoft login doesn't even recognize the email address as Microsoft (it's an .edu address).

Comment: Same for me on Ubuntu 22.04